# scrapy login no work

Tags: python, scrapy

I do not get the login when I call the form post should be because the input names are like arrays for example logn [username] and login [passwords] that's why I do not accept there is some way to send arrays in the name of the inputs? or do it with the input id?

```html
start_urls = ['https://b2b.fluidra.es/customer/account/login']

def parse(self, response):

    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath='//form[@id="login-form"]',
        formdata={
            'login[username]': 'MISUSER@USER.COM',             
            'login[password]': 'XXXXXXXXXX'
        },
        callback=self.start_requests_action
    )
```

then the html code of the form that is sent for the login

```html
<form action="https://b2b.fluidra.es/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cDovL2IyYi5mbHVpZHJhLmVzL2Nhc2NhZGEtc2lsa2Zsb3cuaHRtbA,,/" method="post" id="login-form">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <div class="col2-set">
                <div class="col-1 registered-users">
                    <h2 class="legend">Clientes registrados</h2>
                    <p>Si tienes una cuenta con nosotros, accede usando tu dirección de email.</p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em>Dirección de email</label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="login[username]" value="" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="Dirección de email" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em>Contraseña</label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="Contraseña" type="password">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                                                <li class="note">
                            <a href="https://b2b.fluidra.es/customer/account/forgotpassword/">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                        </li>
                                                <li class="buttons-set">
                            <button type="submit" class="button" name="send" id="send2"><span><span>Entrar</span></span></button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="required">* Campos requeridos</p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var showTooltip = function() {
        this.rememberTip = new Enterprise.Widget.Dialog(
            '¿Qué es esto?',
            '<p>Checking &quot;Remember Me&quot; will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out</p>'+
            '<div class="buttons-set"><button type="button" class="button btn-close"><span><span>Cerrar</span></span></button></div>',
            'popup-remember-tip'
        ),
        $(this.rememberTip.getContent()).select('button.btn-close')[0].onclick = this.rememberTip.hide.bind(this.rememberTip);
        this.rememberTip.show();
        return false;
    }

    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $$('#remember-me-box a').each(function(element) {
            Event.observe(element, 'click', showTooltip);
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
                </div>
                                <div class="col-2 new-users">
                    <h2 class="legend">Nuevos clientes</h2>
                    <p>Sólo usuarios registrados pueden ver precios, realizar pedidos y consultar el estado de estos en nuestra tienda. Para registrarte deberás rellenar el formulario que aparece tras hacer click en Registrarse.</p>
                    <div class="buttons-set">
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.location='https://b2b.fluidra.es/customer/account/create/';"><span><span>Registrarse</span></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="masque">
            <img src="https://b2b.fluidra.es/skin/frontend/default/fluidra/images/bg_items_product1.png" alt="">
        </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: I ran it and it works. I get `Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos` which because I entered a wrong password

Comment: can not login so you put the user and password loads the web but without the login I would like to tell me how to step in the parameters the name of the login login [username] and login [passwords]

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your question

Comment: Pls specify what the output is when you run the script